# Limiting Distributions

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let P be the transition matrix 
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.2& 0.2 & 0.2 \\
0.2 & 0 & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.2 &0.2 \\
0.2 & 0.2 & 0 & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.2 \\
0.2 & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0 & 0.2 & 0.2 \\
0.2 & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0 & 0.2 \\
0.2 & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

I notice that $P_{i,i}=0$ for $i\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ 
Does this imply that a limiting distribution does not exist for transition matrix P?

Comment: It does not. The limiting distribution simply tells you which state you'll end up at "on average" over a sufficiently large number of states; the probability that you'll "stay" at a particular state over infinitely many iterations is usually zero.

Comment: It's not a transition matrix. The row sums are not all equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is a doubly stochastic matrix - notice that both the rows AND columns to 1. It is easy to verify that 
$$\pi = \left(\frac16, \frac16, \frac16, \frac16, \frac16, \frac16\right) $$
is a stationary distribution (i.e. satisfies $\pi=\pi P$).